# is there a conky companion that allows me to read rss feed?

Tags: conky, rss

Everything is in the title. just adding more characters to reach the 30 characters mark.

I could not find one. There was `conkygooglereader` but the Google service has ceased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conky indeed is used for system monitoring such as CPU, HDD, system messages , etc... So I don't think you could find a rss reader.

Instead you can use a similar approach called [screenlets](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screenlets/).

> creenlets are small owner-drawn applications (written in Python) that
>   can be described as "the virtual representation of things
>   lying/standing around on your desk". Sticky notes, clocks, rulers, ...
>   the possibilities are endless.

You can find multiple kings and types from http://gnome-look.org/?xcontentmode=6700.

Now back to what you want. First add the screenlets repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets/ppa

sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install a rss reader called [feedreader-screenlet](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/screenlets_stable/trusty/main/base/feedreader-screenlet)

```
sudo apt-get install feedreader-screenlet
```